# Div alignment side by side with overflow

Tags: css

i want to align this two div elements with float:left side by side. if i add "overflow:hidden", than it doesn't work. But i can't remove this "overflow" attribute.

is there any solution?

**CSS:**

```
#box{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
}

#el1 {
    width:49%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#el2 {
    width:49%;
    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="el1"></div>
</div>

<div id="box">
    <div id="el2"></div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/Ar99F/276)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aldimeola1122/Ar99F/276/

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: @aldimeola1122 Looking through your ~30 questions ... you *really* need to start accepting more answers or people are likely going to start ignoring your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ar99F/280/

Changes:
I removed the float from your inner elements, because that is what was really causing your issue, not the overflow. Also, **you can't have two elements on the page with the *same* id! So I made one `box1` and the other `box2`**

```
#box{   
    width: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
}
#box2{
    width:50%;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;        
}

#el1 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100px;
}
#el2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS is, I think, what you are looking for.

```
#box{
    width:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    float: left;
}

#el1 {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100px;
}
#el2 {
    background-color:blue;
    height:100px;
}
```

By the way, your HTML is wrong, ids should be unique and you have two #box.